# Cmake error while syncing the android project with C++ support

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake

I just used Android Studio new project wizard created a project with C++ support. During the syncing process, Gradle failed and printed this message:

```
[1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_107a1.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
[2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_107a1
FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd .  &&
D:\applications\ndk\android-ndk-r12b\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe
-target armv5te-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain
D:/applications/ndk/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64
--sysroot=D:/applications/ndk/android-ndk-r12b/platforms/android-24/arch-arm
-g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong
-no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float
-fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat
-Werror=format-security -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables
-fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te
-mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack
-Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel
-Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack
-Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--gc-sections
-Wl,-z,nocopyreloc -pie -fPIE -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel
-Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack
-Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--gc-sections
-Wl,-z,nocopyreloc -pie -fPIE CMakeFiles/cmTC_107a1.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
-o cmTC_107a1 -lm && cd ."
Error:error: no such file or directory:
  'CMakeFiles/cmTC_107a1.dir/testCCompiler.c.o'
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt
```

Seems that the process was interuppted during processing CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake.
Anyone knows the usage of "CMakeFiles/cmTC_107a1.dir/testCCompiler.c.o"?

My cmake is the latest version 3.6.3155560.

Comment: Hi, Pan! Have you resolved the problem?

Comment: Not resolved yet. I reported an issue to google long ago, also no progress. [Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37131900).